# Not Calling Success Function After Returning Values from PageMethods With Multiple Parameters C#

Tags: javascript, c#, function, parameters, pagemethods

I am trying to call my OnSuccess function but it didn't call it in the server.

My Code:

```
function Get_Data(option , text){
 //returns 'data', 'data', --not call OnSuccess-- 
 PageMethods.BindSeries(option,text,OnSuccess); 
}

function OnSuccess(Response){//content-logic}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking everything, my codes are just fine. I tried to deploy my codes in different application server for testing purposes and it did worked fine when testing it. Now, we are checking on the possible pipeline issue why my code is not working in its UAT server. Possible that my codes is not published / compile properly through jenkins pipeline.